# Sharepoint 2010 ClientContext with kerberos & a 401 unauthorised

Tags: sharepoint, kerberos

I can get a remote console app talking to a NTLM Sharepoint site with ClientContext and I can it talking to a remote Kerberos Sharepoint box with HttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

But I cannot get it talking to the Kerberos Sharepoint box with CientContext.  Any additional pointers would be gratefully recieved.

```
string siteURL = "http://my.remote.sharepoint";             
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteURL);           
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();           
cc.Add(new Uri(siteURL), "Kerberos", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);            
ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;         
ctx.Credentials =cc;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This code confirms that I can access "my.remote.sharepoint" with KRB
//       HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(siteURL);
//       myHttpWebRequest.Credentials = cc;
//       myHttpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;              
//       HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Web remoteWeb = ctx.Web;
ctx.Load(remoteWeb);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//401 unauthorised returned from here
```

Wireshark suggests that it returns the initial 401 & then gives up!  Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Please check if a `SPN` is registered for that host and a reverse DNS entry exists.